# Alias and provider name unknown for github library

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I am trying to install this github library:

https://github.com/robholmes/term-extractor

I used composer by adding this in `composer.json` under `"require"`:

```
"robholmes/term-extractor": "dev-master"
```

However, I'm not sure what I would put in the `app.php` config file under `providers` and `aliases`. What would be the lines I would add there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Laravel specific package. No need to add service providers, as they don't exist.

```
composer require robholmes/term-extractor dev-master
```

Instead, just include it in your controller for use, etc:

```
use TermExtractor\TermExtractor;
```

To test it works (it should), in your controller method just return this:

```
$term_extractor = new TermExtractor();
return dd($term_extractor);
```

Comment: Thanks! Question: why is it `use TermExtractor\TermExtractor`? Why not just `use TermExtractor`?

Comment: That would be an alias...facade, etc. Which you should shy away from anyways. That's more Laravel package type of sh*t.. :)

Comment: Yes, but why is `TermExtractor` there twice? What does each refer to?